Why would 1Gb flash drive display as 69Gb in Ubuntu Disk utility (22.04)
I was looking at some old flash drives in Disks utility and found one with strange information. At the Top of the Disks utility screen, it says /dev/sdb is 69Gb. Model: RW8021 Flash Disk (1.0)
The space allocation image shows a 1Gb partition (/dev/sdb1) titled Partition 1 on the left and then 68Gb of free space on the right. The partition is FAT16 (bootable).
The label on the disk itself says 1Gb. So where does Disks find another 68Gb?
The disk doesn't display in Files.

Check the stick with programs from the f3 (fight fake flash) package -- it might not even be 1GB!
